# Sending and receiving faxes from a web app

Tags: web-applications, fax

Facilitating fax programmatically like hellofax.com or faxitnice.com can be done pretty easily using 3rd party APIs.

How do those 3rd party API providers facilitate faxes on the backend?

Answer (score 2):

Most companies most likely have a [fax server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fax_server) that they interface with via script.